# Knockout computed creates dependency for observable that is written to but not read

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this code in a 'widget'. Value is the widgets value, other is a source of data from elsewhere in the app. The computed creates a subscription for value even though it is never read. This means when I update value, comp is run and value is set back to other..

```
value = ko.observable(1); // Widgets value
other = ko.observable('a'); // Somewhere else in app

comp = ko.computed(function () {
    value(other());
    doSomeThingElse();
});

value(2);
// comp is run
value() === 'a'; // true
```

Basically I need comp to only run if other is changed. I see there is now a peek function but that is only for read. Why does a computed even create a subscription for an observable that is never read? This is very frustrating. Is there any way around this?

The comp functions are used on a widget to set their data from external sources, the actual layout of a widget would be:

```
new Widget({
    id: 'widget',
    initial: 5,
    observables: {
        data: function () {
            var data = client.get('data'); // observable
            this.value(data);
            this.color(data.length ? 'red' : 'green');
        }
    }
})
```

When the widget is created it makes a new computed from observables.data. We would hope to keep this simple api without having to do manual subscriptions which would complicate the widget.

**Edit:**
The problem was infact an error with my code, the above examples were suppost to be simplified but actually cut out the issue. See this fiddle if interested http://jsfiddle.net/dominata/hu6Fr/.

After consideration we are going to use this model instead of using computeds purely for side effects. I agree this is more how they are intended to be used.

```
new Widget({
    id: 'widget',
    initial: 5,
    value: function () {
        return client.get('data');
    },
    color: function () {
        return client.get('data').length ? 'red' : 'green';
    }
})
```

Comment: In general this is not a good practice that your computed has side effects namely setting outside variables.

Comment: I have considered this again and decided that I agree our computeds for side effects is not the best idea and may be confusing leading to bad working practice, ie using them to set things that should not be set with them. We are going to user computeds for their return values and simply have more of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `value` in your computed does not create a subscription.  You would have a subscription to `other`.  The only question would be if you access `value` as part of `doSomethingElse`.

Here is a fiddle that shows that the computed is initially evaluated, but not evaluated after updating `value`: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/exV92/

I agree with @nemesv that you would likely want to be careful with setting an observable in the computed. Your current case should work (barring what is doing in `doSomethingElse`).

Another option might be to use a manual subscription.  If you want to update `value` only when `other` changes, then you can do:

```
other.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    value(newValue);
    doSomethingElse();
});
```

With a manual subscription it will only trigger when that specific observable changes, so you don't have to worry about which dependencies you are accessing.

Comment: Well that embarrassing, clearly I hadn't checked my own example. I put together a more complete fiddle to demonstrate the problem, and in doing so realised the error of my ways.
Value was a wrapper function which did get and set on the actual observable but the wrapper function was always reading the value of the observable! Complete oversight. Here's a fiddle for anyone interested.
http://jsfiddle.net/dominata/hu6Fr/